# How to read multiple text lines

Tags: c++, text, text-files, lines

In my text file ("UsernamePassword.txt"), there are multiple lines of Usernames and Passwords. When I tried logging in using the Username and Password on the 2nd line or 3rd line, it brings me to the "invalid username or password" part. Only the 1st line of username and password works.

Any suggestion on how to read the multiple lines?

```
{
    fstream inFile;
    string user, pass, username, password;
    int choice;
    Logo();
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    inFile.open("UsernamePassword.txt");
    if (!inFile)
        cout << "Unable to Open File";
    else 
    {       
        while (username != user)
        cout << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "               Please enter username: ";
        cin >> user;
        cout << "               Please enter password: ";
        cin >> pass;
        {
            inFile >> username >> password;

            if (user == username && pass == password)
            {
                system("cls");
                cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
                cout << "\t            ****************************************** " << endl;
                cout << "\t            **  !!!   Welcome to CherryLunch   !!!  ** " << endl;
                cout << "\t            ****************************************** " << endl;
                cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
                system("pause");
                system("cls");

                MainMenu();

            }
            else
            {           
                cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
                cout << "\t              !!!   Invalid Username or Password   !!!" << endl<<endl;
                cout << "\t                    ***   Please try again   ***" << endl;
                cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;

                system("pause");
                system("cls");
            }
        }
    }
    inFile.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Did you put your while statement on the wrong line? Also, show a snippet of your text file.

Comment: move the `while (username != user)` one line  below `cin >> pass;` I think that is probably what you intended to do. That isn't the only thing wrong though.

Comment: This is just another symptom of the same coding errors involved in [your other question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185382/how-to-stop-a-while-loop).  The good answer(s) there are applicable here too.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us the whole code - but I have placed comments in your code (various places) to indicate whether you wanted to do this willingly or did it by mistake:

```
{
fstream inFile;
string user, pass, username, password;
int choice;
Logo();
cout << endl << endl << endl;
inFile.open("UsernamePassword.txt");
if (!inFile)
    cout << "Unable to Open File";
else 
{       
    while (username != user)  // Only the following run will repeat ( if this is the intention?)
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "               Please enter username: ";
    cin >> user;
    cout << "               Please enter password: ";
    cin >> pass;
    {  // This is scoped operation
        inFile >> username >> password;

        if (user == username && pass == password)
        {

            system("cls");
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout << "\t            ****************************************** " << endl;
            cout << "\t            **  !!!   Welcome to CherryLunch   !!!  ** " << endl;
            cout << "\t            ****************************************** " << endl;
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            MainMenu();

        }
        else
        {           
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout << "\t              !!!   Invalid Username or Password   !!!" << endl<<endl;
            cout << "\t                    ***   Please try again   ***" << endl;
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        } // End of inner else
    } // This is the end of scoped operation
}  // End of Outer else
inFile.close();
```